# DQN with 2D input breaks

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I need a second set of eyes please. I have a DQN algorithm that works fine for cart-pole and I tried to use it for some 2D stuff but it falls apart.

I benchmark it with regular cartpolev1 except I reshape my 4 observations (by duplicating the observations into each row) into [4,4] array
Which I feed to neural network as a tensor of shape [batchSize, 1, 4, 4] (I suspect the batchSize is what makes it all fall apart for Q learning)

Warning, this is C# code using torchsharp not pytorch:

How I convert observation to tensor:

```
 protected Tensor StateToTensor(T state, bool unsqueeze = true)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case float[] stateArray:
            return tensor(stateArray).to(myDevice);
        case float[,] stateMatrix:
            var tensor2D = tensor(stateMatrix).to(myDevice);
            if (unsqueeze)
            {
                return tensor2D.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0);  // adding an extra dimension at the beginning
            }
            else
            {
                return tensor2D.unsqueeze(0);  // keep the tensor as it is
            }
        default:
            throw new InvalidCastException("State must be either float[] or float[,]");
    }
}
```

My NN:

```
public DQN2D(string name, long h, long w, long outputs) : base(name)
{
    conv1 = Conv2d(1, 64, kernelSize: 1, stride: 1);

    long output_height = CalculateConvOutputSize(h, 1); // output size of conv1
    long output_width = CalculateConvOutputSize(w, 1);


    linear_input_size = output_height * output_width * 64;

    flatten = Flatten();

    fc1 = Linear(linear_input_size, 2048);
    fc2 = Linear(2048, 1024);
    head = Linear(1024, outputs);

    RegisterComponents();
}

public override Tensor forward(Tensor x)
{


    x = functional.relu(conv1.forward(x));

    x = flatten.forward(x);

    x = functional.relu(fc1.forward(x));
    x = functional.relu(fc2.forward(x));
    return head.forward(x);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        conv1.Dispose();
        fc1.Dispose();
        fc2.Dispose();
        head.Dispose();
        flatten.Dispose();
        ClearModules();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

And here is my Optimize step:

```
public virtual void OptimizeModel()
{
    if (myReplayBuffer.Length < myOptions.batchSize)
        return;

    //TODO: Transition/s is a ridiculous name from pytorch DQN example, should this be changed?
    List<Transition<T>> transitions = myReplayBuffer.Sample();

    // Transpose the batch (convert batch of Transitions to Transition of batches)
    List<T> batchStates = transitions.Select(t => t.state).ToList();
    List<int> batchActions = transitions.Select(t => t.action).ToList();
    List<float> batchRewards = transitions.Select(t => t.reward).ToList();
    List<T> batchNextStates = transitions.Select(t => t.nextState).ToList();
    // Compute a mask of non-final states and concatenate the batch elements
    Tensor nonFinalMask = tensor(batchNextStates.Select(s => s != null).ToArray()).to(myDevice);
    Tensor stateBatch = stack(batchStates.Select(s => StateToTensor(s, false)).ToArray()).to(myDevice);

    //This clumsy part is to account for situation where batch is picked where each episode has only 1 step
    //Why 1 step episode is a problem anyway? It should still have Q value for the action taken
    Tensor[] nonFinalNextStatesArray = batchNextStates.Where(s => s != null).Select(s => StateToTensor(s, false)).ToArray();
    Tensor nonFinalNextStates;
    if (nonFinalNextStatesArray.Length > 0)
    {
        nonFinalNextStates = stack(nonFinalNextStatesArray).to(myDevice);
        // Continue with the rest of your code
    }
    else
    {
        return;
        // Handle the case when all states are terminal
    }

    Tensor actionBatch = stack(batchActions.Select(a => tensor(new int[] { a }).to(torch.int64)).ToArray()).to(myDevice);
    Tensor rewardBatch = stack(batchRewards.Select(r => tensor(r)).ToArray()).to(myDevice);

    // Compute Q(s_t, a)
    Tensor stateActionValues = myPolicyNet.forward(stateBatch).gather(1, actionBatch).to(myDevice);

    // Compute V(s_{t+1}) for all next states.
    Tensor nextStateValues = zeros(new long[] { myOptions.batchSize }).to(myDevice);
    using (no_grad())
    {
        nextStateValues.masked_scatter_(nonFinalMask, myTargetNet.forward(nonFinalNextStates).max(1).values);
    }
    // Compute the expected Q values
    Tensor expectedStateActionValues = (nextStateValues * myOptions.GAMMA) + rewardBatch;

    // Compute Huber loss
    SmoothL1Loss criterion = torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss();
    Tensor loss = criterion.forward(stateActionValues, expectedStateActionValues.unsqueeze(1));

    // Optimize the model
    myOptimizer.zero_grad();
    loss.backward();
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_value_(myPolicyNet.parameters(), 100);
    myOptimizer.step();
}
```

So this works fine for 1d cartpole but my 2d version just seems to select actions at random. I tried to track down the problem but it just seems okay for me if some pytorch or reinforcement learning expert could have a look and tell me if I am doing something dumb when reshaping tensors I would be so grateful!

Answer (score 0):

After many MANY hours I've finally come to realise that issue was caused by float[,] being reference types while float[] is value type. In nutshell my replayBuffer was getting scrambled each time I added new experience.

This is fixed with DeepCopy

```
public T DeepCopy(T input)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsArray)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This method can only be used with arrays!");
        }

        // Handle nulls
        if (ReferenceEquals(input, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        var rank = ((Array)(object)input).Rank;
        var lengths = new int[rank];
        for (int i = 0; i < rank; ++i)
            lengths[i] = ((Array)(object)input).GetLength(i);

        var clone = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T).GetElementType(), lengths);

        Array.Copy((Array)(object)input, clone, ((Array)(object)input).Length);

        return (T)(object)clone;
    }
```